# Android PrintJob null Intent

Tags: java, android

I am facing an issue with the PrintJob class.
(https://developer.android.com/training/printing/html-docs.html#print-job)

The documentation throws some code in here and it works, but in can't understand what it is really going on.

I have to print the content of a webview in a PDF file. I manage to do it with this documentation on an Android 7 device.

When i test the app on an Android 9 device, I get an `ActivityNotFoundException`. So what I am understanding here is that the code in the documentation send an `Intent` for an activity able to print PDF under the hood (no `startActivity()` in my code).

When I look to the error closer i see that:

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle null
```

Does this mean that my device doesn't have a Printer ?

Here is the code:

```
if(getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_PRINTING)) {
    Logger.logV("PDF", "Printing is available");

    PrintManager printManager = (PrintManager) getSystemService(Context.PRINT_SERVICE);
    String filename = "My document name";
    PrintDocumentAdapter printAdapter = webView.createPrintDocumentAdapter(filename.toString());
    printManager.print(filename.toString(), printAdapter, new PrintAttributes.Builder().build());
}
```

Complete stack trace:

```java
2020-02-12 13:41:46.923 18074-18074/com.ufrst.app.trombi E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.ufrst.app.trombi, PID: 18074
    android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle null
        at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:2018)
        at android.app.Activity.startIntentSenderForResultInner(Activity.java:4947)
        at android.app.Activity.startIntentSenderForResult(Activity.java:4914)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startIntentSenderForResult(FragmentActivity.java:705)
        at android.app.Activity.startIntentSenderForResult(Activity.java:4881)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startIntentSenderForResult(FragmentActivity.java:690)
        at android.app.Activity.startIntentSender(Activity.java:5104)
        at android.app.Activity.startIntentSender(Activity.java:5071)
        at android.print.PrintManager.print(PrintManager.java:536)
        at com.ufrst.app.trombi.ui.ActivityVueTrombi.createWebPrintJob(ActivityVueTrombi.java:377)
        at com.ufrst.app.trombi.ui.ActivityVueTrombi.onOptionsItemSelected(ActivityVueTrombi.java:402)
        at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:3629)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(FragmentActivity.java:384)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onMenuItemSelected(AppCompatActivity.java:219)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onMenuItemSelected(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:109)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onMenuItemSelected(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:109)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.ToolbarActionBar$2.onMenuItemClick(ToolbarActionBar.java:64)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar$1.onMenuItemClick(Toolbar.java:207)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionMenuView$MenuBuilderCallback.onMenuItemSelected(ActionMenuView.java:781)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:840)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.SubMenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(SubMenuBuilder.java:90)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:158)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:991)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuPopup.onItemClick(MenuPopup.java:128)
        at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:362)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1689)
        at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:4130)
        at android.widget.AbsListView$7.run(AbsListView.java:6608)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6986)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1445)
```

Comment: can you include where you declare the intent?

Comment: I didnt declare any intent, i think its been made when i call `printManager.print()`